# How to use class methods as property initializers?

Tags: typescript

I cannot init a property in constructor through a private method.

```
export class Storage {
  /**
   * Complains:
   * TS2564: Property 'meta' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.
   */
  private meta: {
    ver: number
  }

  constructor() {
    this.initLocalData()
  }

  private initLocalData() {
    this.meta = { ver: 0 }
  }
}
```

I want to reuse the initializer to reduce code size. How to fix the warning?

Comment: Just define the `meta` with non null assertion `private meta!: { ver: number }` (you know that you're initializing it in constructor)

Comment: Are you going to use `initLocalData` somewhere else besides the constructor?

Comment: @AlekseyL.Yes. Somewhere in the class do reinit for them.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an initializer instead of repeating the `meta` property?

```
export class Storage {
  #meta = { ver: 0 }
}
```

Or, if you need the class field to be private only for typings, rather than fully private:

```
export class Storage {
  private meta = { ver: 0 }
}
```

Comment: I just want to reuse the init logic. They are used in other part of the class and I want to manage them in one method.

Answer (score -2):

You could make `initLocalData` public and just call that directly instead of using the constructor.

Comment: These meta should be controlled. They cannot be affected by others.